# How to select and copy content from the terminal (ATL + CTRL + F1)

Tags: command-line, mouse, console

When in the 'lower level terminal' (not sure how this is called), the one opened by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, how can I copy the content of the command I used there, since there is no mouse and I can not move my cursor out for the command line?

Comment: @Beniamin paste it here so i can get some support : )

Comment: Do you want to copy the command, or its output?

Comment: The output, in this instance i am trying to run X -config and i am getting a couple of errors

Comment: you could just redirect the output to a file with > or &>

Comment: @aking1012 thanks, that was it, can you please post that as an answers so i can vote it ?

Comment: It is called "virtual console": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just redirect the output to a file with `>` or `&>`... I was asked to move it from comments to answers, so here it is.

By the way, a couple notes:

Putting `>` in between a command and a filename will overwrite the current contents of the file with standard out.

Putting `>>` appends to a file.

Putting a `&` before the redirector will also catch standard error (in Bash > 4).

Answer (score 5):

The last used command history is usually stored in your **history file** (`.bash_history`). You can open this file with the editor-of-your-choice and copy contents.

As for manipulating the command-line of the console window, you can rely on the command line editing functions of the bash shell. They are discussed in the **READLINE** section of the Bash manual page (`man bash`). But they will not allow you to paste the copied part into an editor.

Another way to work around this is to use the **screen** utility. There are several introductory [tutorials](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) on the web. Screen has a copy and paste function:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get into copy mode.
2. By moving around the cursor keys you can position to the first character of your selected region, then press <kbd>Space</kbd>. You now have set the first mark.
3. Move the cursor to the end of the text you'd like to select and press <kbd>Space</kbd>. You have now copied the selected region into the buffer.
4. To paste the buffer press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>]</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

To send the output of a command to a file, you can use [redirection.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

For example, you could send your `dmesg` command to a file with

`dmesg > ~/Documents/output.txt`

Then the output will write to that file instead of the screen. When you come back to the GUI, you can find the file in your Documents folder and access the contents.

Comment: Thank you root45. I voted up but i ll kuddo Aking as he was the first to suggest this answer in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

GPM is just what you need & very useful. While in the console (`ctrl+alt+f1`), you can `copy` by dragging the left-hand mouse button, and then `paste` by clicking the right-hand mouse button.

Comment: Why? what does it do?  You might want to edit your answer and explain for the benefit of the OP and other users

Comment: This really is the answer and needs way more upvotes. You can even launch a second TTY (alt + f2), start gpm (`systemctl start gpm`), switch back to your previous tty, and then copy/paste whatever you need. I searched for hours to find this, and most answers are the unhelpful "use screen, next time" that don't solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

There's several ways to go around this.  The simplest is with `xclip` and I've saved for the last.

hbdgaf's answer presents one solution - redirection. Here's two variations on the theme - redirection with named pipe and `byobu`. First requires no additional software installation, while `byobu` has to be installed.

**Option 1: named pipe**

When you run a command and use pipeline `|` to redirect its output to another command, that is called an anonymous pipe - it exists for a set moment of time. Named pipe , on the other hand, is a special sort of file, where data goes in, and then goes out.

Here's the steps to make it work:

1. create the named pipe with `mkfifo /tmp/myPipe`
2. run the command you want and redirect the output to `/tmp/myPipe` . For instance, `sudo apt-get install byobu > /tmp/myPipe`. Notice, that the command will wait until you release the output from `myPipe`. Use `&` to make it wait in the background, and let you continue using the terminal, like so `sudo apt-get install byobu > /tmp/myPipe &` . Notice also that stdout will go into the pipe, but stderr will go to the screen. If you want both stderr and stdout in the pipe , use `&>` instead of `>`

   3. come back to the GUI, and release the output from that pipe with `cat /tmp/myPipe`. Now you can copy the output with mouse and keyboard.

**Option 2: shared session in byobu**

As for `byobu`, the basic idea is that it creates a shared session. You launch byobu in TTY and GUI terminal, and you see the same output there and there. I'd suggest launching TTY first, because that way it's cleaner. So let's say I launch byobu in TTY2 run `df;free` , go to GUI, launch `gnome-terminal` then call `byobu`, and voila - I see the same output that I saw in TTY !

**Option 3: xclip, the easiest way**

Suppose I wanted to copy output of `df` command. All I'd have to do with `xclip` is this:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0 ; df | xclip -sel clip
```

And it will be already in your GUI clipboard !

There's a small catch however - `xclip` is not a native app, and has to be installed via `sudo apt-get install xclip`

Of course typing all that in can get repetitive, so you can create a `.bashrc` function to do the job. Simply copy and paste the function bellow into your `.bashrc` file, save the file, and now each time you log in , you have a simple command to copy output to clipboard

```
function toClipboard
{
  export DISPLAY=:0
  "$@" | xclip -sel clip

}
```

And you'd run it as `$ toClipboard df -h` , so notice that you can run command with parameters.

**Option 4: script**

There exists a command called `script` which has exactly that purpose - record what you see on command line into a file. You can either run it first, and then type output in it's shell, and then exit; or you can call screen with `--command` flag, like so `script --command "df -h"`

However, there's a drawback - the output file may contain special characters. [Reffer here for info on how to clean the output up](https://superuser.com/q/236930/418028)

**Option 5: /dev/vcsX**

[As shown by Giles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/95916/85039) from U&L site, one can actually dump contents of tty onto another terminal's stdout. Suppose we want to dump tty2. The command for that is

```
 cat /dev/vcs1
```

Draw back of this method is that if your terminal is set to certain level of scrollback lines, you can get only partial output.